# PaClient Error Deploy App Store

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-ios

I take this error when i deploy to App Store from Delphi Dx 10 Seattle

```
[PAClient Error] Error: E0264 Unable to execute '"/usr/bin/codesign" --deep -s "iPhone Distribution: xxx (xxx)" -f "/Users/mac/PAServer/scratch-dir/Huseyin-Yeni Hesap/xxx.app"' (Error 1)
```

Comment: delete the profile from keychain and download again from developer portal

Comment: @techlover I did that but i taking same error again

Comment: Do you have hotfix http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30398 ?

Comment: Yes but i gaing take this error

Comment: Its ok. created when i deleted Certificates on Key Chain but Application Loader says to me its not code sign's Application for this ipa when i will try to upload my app on the Applicaiton Loader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First delete all signatures and certificates from your computer. Then re-create your certificates and signatures. Then set up Paserveri. Then this order is required for xe7 version. I have found a solution like this